# MATLAB R2007b: display final weights and bias in MLP code

Tags: matlab

I've built a code to train a MultiLayer Perceptron in MATBAL R2007b, and I need a command to show me the final weights and the final bias of the network after the patterns are trained. I can't use the command `wb = getwb(net)`, that comes in version R2010, because I **must** use this older version of Matlab.

The code:

```
clear all
close all
clc
disp('Creating the input patterns x...')
x = [0 0; 0 1; 1 0; 1 1]'
pause(1);
disp('Creating the desired outputs (targets)y...')
yd = [0 1 1 0]
pause(1); disp('Creating network with 2 units in hidden layer.')
% 2 Neurons in the hidden layer.
nnet = newff(x,yd,2,{'tansig','tansig'});
pause(1);
disp('Training the network...')
nnet = train(nnet, x, yd);
disp('Testing the patterns')
y=sim(nnet,[0 0; 0 1; 1 0; 1 1]')
```

I really need this and I suppose it's a simple command because the final weights and bias is already stored internally in the fucntion, but I need to show it. Any help?

Comment: *2007b*? There have been 23 releases of MATLAB since then, you'll struggle to find anyone who can run your MCVE in a comparable setup, although thanks for providing one! Can you use `get(nnet)` to view all of the properties, and hunt down what you want from there?

Comment: I ended up finding something that works, but in the end I'll use the 2018b version anyways. Thanks!

Comment: If you found something that worked then feel free to answer your own question and mark it as accepted - it may help future visitors with the same issue!

Comment: Ok, I just did that!

Comment: Great, a good backwards compatible solution with decent comments, nice contribution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding those commands that seems to work in every version of Matlab, the old and the new:

```
weight_final = net.IW{1,1} %here is a variable receiving the final weights vector, 
%notice that "{1,1}" coordinates changes according to the number of inputs and outputs.
bias_final = net.b{1} %here is a variable receiving the final bias vector. 
% "{1}" also changes according to the number of inputs/outputs.
```